# Twin NAT and multiple GWs, routing issue

Tags: routing, nat

the overview of my situation can be seen here:

[image: overview]

I have multiple overlapping networks here, namely 10.0.0.0/8 and 10.64.5.0/24 and 10.64.95.0/24. I've decided to separate them via NAT - using 192.168.88.0 network. The other NAT ("Red") works fine and separates another subnet.
R2 and R3 are Mikrotik routers, their respective configs:

R1 is a SOHO TP-LINK MR3220, which is default GW for the machines in pink (10.0.0.0/8 subnet). It serves as an Internet gateway for them.
The problem is, I can ping 192.168.88.1 / 2 / 3 (in essence, R2 interface) from "blue" IPs (192.168.40.71), but cannot ping 192.168.40.71 from "pink" machines - the ping is sent to their default GW (10.0.0.1 = TPLink), and the router in turn has static route set - 192.168.40.0 via 10.64.203.88.
However, the traceroute to 192.168.88.4 (R3 interface) stops at R2 (10.64.203.88).

I can ping 192.168.88.1 from 192.168.40.71 (blue), but not the other way around. Mikrotik labeled R2 can ping 40.71 however.

All firewalls are disabled.

I suspect I messed something up in the default GW/static routes, but do not know where.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to have overlapping networks? I've seen this happen when companies merge. This won't scale and will be a headache to support. I would give a serious thought to redesigning the network with subnets that do not overlap... You'll be making your life a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's a headache - however, I "inherited" the network setup and now I'm trying to do as much as possible without actually redesigning anything physically. At some point in the future (sooner than later) this is going to happen anyway, but I required a quick and dirty solution :-)

Comment: Does R2 have a route to 192.168.40.2/24 via 192.168.88.4? And does R3 have a route to 10.0.0.0/8 (pink) via 192.168.88.1

Comment: When companies with overlapping network addresses merge, they often use NAT as a temporary measure until one or both of the networks gets readdressed. It is not your typical inside source NAT. You use outside source NAT for this. Unfortunately, your TP-Link device is off-topic here because the vendor does not offer a paid support option.

Comment: Regarding the R2 route - yes it does: http://i68.tinypic.com/2czwnq1.png

Comment: "And does R3 have a route to 10.0.0.0/8 (pink) via 192.168.88.1". What about R3? R3 won't automatically know about the routes on R2 apart from the directly connected route (192.168.88.0/24).

Comment: Thanks! I could stare at the routing table for hours and still would not have noticed it. Now it works, it seems. http://i68.tinypic.com/ogctqw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R3 does not have a route to 10.0.0.0/8 (pink) via 192.168.88.1.